# Relación uno a cero o uno sobre la misma tabla con clave foráenea en propiedad

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

Necesito crear una relación de uno a cero o uno sobre la misma tabla, la relación la tengo definida correctamente, el problema viene cuando necesito que la ForeignKey quede almacenada en una propiedad de la misma clase.

Cuando ejecuto el código EF no hace caso a la notación ( ForeignKey("Padre") ) y crea una clave propia.

El código consta de una única clase "Persona" cada persona puede tener un hijo y un padre, nunca un padre tendrá mas de un hijo ni un hijo mas de un padre claro.

Clase Persona

```
 public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Padre")]
    public int? PadreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Persona Padre { get; set; }
    public virtual Persona Hijo { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating del DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
           .HasOptional(p => p.Hijo)
           .WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.Padre);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Padre)
            .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.Hijo);

    }
```

Resultado de la creación del EF (versión 6.1)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Personas] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Nombre] [nvarchar](max),
    [PadreId] [int],
    [Padre_Id] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Personas] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)


-- Executing at 04/04/2017 12:26:08 +02:00

-- Completed in 32 ms with result: -1



CREATE INDEX [IX_Padre_Id] ON [dbo].[Personas]([Padre_Id])


-- Executing at 04/04/2017 12:26:08 +02:00

-- Completed in 29 ms with result: -1



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Personas] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Personas_dbo.Personas_Padre_
Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Padre_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Personas] ([Id])
```

Como se puede observar en este ultimo código SQL al crear las tablas EF no hace caso al ForeignKey especificado en la propiedad PadreId y crea su propio ForeignKey.

Alguien me sabe decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos y gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberas ver de definir el `Map()` o `HasFereignKey()` para indicar la propiedad que defina el campo, entonces en la mapping usarias

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.Padre)
        .WithOptionalDependent();
        .Map(d => d.MapKey("PadreId");
```

De esta forma indicas que nombre tendra el campo que los conecta

[How to setup Entity Framework Code first to have only one side 0 to 1 relationship](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-setup-entity-framework-code-first-to-have-only-one-side-0-to-1-relationship)

Tambien podrias hacer uso de

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.Padre)
        .WithMany()
        .HasFereignKey(p => p.PadreId);
```

Para la relacion con el hijo realizas lo mismo

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
        .HasOptional(p => p.Hijo)
        .WithOptionalDependent();
        .Map(d => d.MapKey("HijoId");
```

Comment: Con Map ya lo había probado y no funciona correctamente retorna el siguiente error (PadreId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'PadreId' is already defined.) 
Con la opción de HasForeignKey funciona bien la relación con el padre, pero con el hijo vuelvo a tener el mismo problema (HijoId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique) mirando el articulo que me has pasado ya pone que no es posible, pero también pone una alternativa que es la que estoy usando.

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Intentaste definiendo la propiedad   `public int? HijoId { get; set; }`   y asi hacer uso del HasFereignKey()

Comment: El código final a sido este:
           modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
                   .HasOptional(p => p.Padre)
                   .WithMany()
                   .HasForeignKey(p => p.PadreId);


           modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()
               .HasOptional(p => p.Hijo)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.HijoId);

Comment: genial, me alegro que se resolviera

Answer (score 0):

El decorador  `[ForeignKey("Padre")]` va sobre la propiedad de navegación Padre  no sobre la propiedad que lo tienes y  debería quedar así

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }    
    public int PadreId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PadreId")]
    public virtual Persona Padre { get; set; }
    public virtual Persona Hijo { get; set; }
}
```